# NetBeans + Mercurial + SSH = Endless Pull/Push

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, ssh

I have well working Mercurial. I can push/pull through cmd commands. But in NetBeans push/pull lasts forever. I've tried to push to BitBucket over http and it worked. But the same thing over ssh didn't. And the same ssh push with 'hg push ssh://...' worked.

What's wrong with NetBeans? It may be some option i should change or smth.

Comment: Post your output with --verbose and --debug so we can see where it's stalling out.  Could be authentication/authorization or data xfer.

Comment: sending hello command
sending between command
remote: Permission denied (publickey).
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!

What do i do with publickey? I've generated one in ~/.ssh/id_rsa, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i've managed the issue. I needed to upload my public key in bitbucket's profile. And put public key in authorized_keys file at my server. After that authorization is passwordless, using keys and NetBeans pulls/pushes ok.