# Mercurial "hg clone" for SSH works in terminal but throws a "no suitable response from remote hg" in NetBeans

Tags: macos, netbeans, mercurial, clone

Operating System: Mac OS X 10.8.4
IDE: Netbeans 7.3.1
Mercurial Version 2.7

I have added this into the .hgrc file under /Users/MyUsername

```
[ui] 
remotecmd = /opt/local/bin/hg
```

I managed to do a hg clone for a repository over SSH perfectly fine using terminal but when I use NetBeans to do the same it produces this exception:

```
no suitable response from remote hg!
```

This is the command that I used in the terminal:

```
hg clone ssh://username@hostname/pathname
```

I have also read this page: [Cloning a Mercurial repository over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431884/cloning-a-mercurial-repository-over-ssh) but it still produces the same exception on NetBeans.

Would appreciate any help from anyone who has had this problem and managed to overcome it.

Thank you.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548053/netbeans-mercurial-ssh-endless-pull-push

Comment: Thanks @black_wizard but it still did not help me. However, I managed to find the solution after 48 hours scouring through tutorials and guides...

https://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/using_mercurial_over_ssh_without